# Is 0.999999999 the same as 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

0.99999999999 divided by 1 = 1 / 9 = 0.11111111111111

1    divided by 9 = 1 / 9 = 0.111111111111

So, does that make 1 = 0.99999999999999

Comment: their distance is as tiny as you want so...

Comment: For what you have written, no.

Comment: But $0.999\cdots = 1$ exactly

Comment: $0.999 \dotsc$ divided by 1 is $0.999 \dotsc$.

Comment: But $0.99999999999999=1-0.00000000000001<1$.  SNCR

Comment: 1 divided by 9 is $0.111\dots$ (with an infinite number of $1$s), not $0.111111111111$.

Comment: @Vicfred, if the OP meant the infinite periodic decimal expansion $\;0.99\dot{9}\;$ , then this number is *exactly* $\;1\;$....which means, of course, that it is "as close as desired" to one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that:
$$
0.a_1a_2....=\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10^2}+....
$$
Then it can be seen that:
$$
0.9999....=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{10^2}+....=\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}=1.
$$
Another way to see that is:

$$
0.9999....=9(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10^2}+....)=9\times 0.1111...
$$
But then $0.1111...=\frac{1}{9}$ which means that $9\times 0.1111...=1$.

---

This means that the convention of representing real numbers in decimals has the difficulty of having non-unique representation. Therefore $0.99999999$ and $1$ both represents the identity element of multiplication for real numbers.